# JavaScript functions stops after a certain if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I recently tried to re-use a (working!) javascript function and detected a strange behaviour: After a certain if statement within a for-loop the function stopps. I don't see any reason.

If a change the actual if condition to "1==1", it all works fine. But with the code being as above I get the first alert ('here we go') but I never get the second alert. So, the problem can't be connected witht the loop (being endless or something like that). But other than that I'm absolutely confused and helpless. (Tested with Firefox 26 and Internet Explorer 11)

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function my_function(number_of_divs)
           {
             for (var k = 0; k <= number_of_divs; k++)
               {
                var index = k;
                if (document.getElementsByName("text_levels")[index].style.display == 'block')
                 {
                  alert('Here we go');
                 } 
               }
              alert('This is never shown');
           }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void" onclick="my_function(1)">Click</a>
        <div name="text_levels" style="display:block">The content of a div element</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be '==='?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger like firebug for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error console tells you what the problem is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

You'll need to perform a bounds check inside your `if` statement:

```
var index = k, 
    levels = document.getElementsByName("text_levels"),
    levelLength = levels.length;

    if(index < levels.length && levels[index].style.display == 'block')
    {
        alert('Here we go');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is you have only one elements with particular name and array indexing starts with zero so you stop at less than condition.

```
for (var k = 0; k < number_of_divs; k++)
```

because when it try to call with `index=1` the following statement throw the error:

```
document.getElementsByName("text_levels")[index].style.display == 'block'
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/4U4SV/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line

```
k <= number_of_divs
```

It should have been

```
k < number_of_divs
```

Since there is only one `text_levels`, it will let the loop to access the second element (element at index `1`), which is not there. So, it fails with an error.